# ingress return 404 not found when use minikube ip

Tags: kubernetes, curl, centos7, minikube, nginx-ingress

I use ingress in minikube

kubectl get ingress

```
http-ingress   nginx   example.com   192.168.49.2   80      44m
```

I edited /etc/hosts
192.168.49.2   example.com

when I use curl example.com  it is work.
but when I use curl minikube ip  (curl 192.168.49.2) return 404 not found